# Rails - how to insert/render a file inside a View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

in index.html.erb, I would like to know how to insert index.js.erb, something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    <%= render =>"home/index.js.erb" %>
});
</script>
```

Any ideas on how to just insert the index.js.erb file ?

thanks

Comment: Do you mean display the contents of index.js.erb instead of rendering it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<%= File.read "#{RAILS_ROOT}/app/views/home/index.js.erb" %>
```

Comment: Instead of using RAILS_ROOT, use ::Rails.root  

`::Rails.root.join('public','images','logo.png')`  

(as per [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9192795/rails-root-not-longer-valid-when-loading-images-with-the-prawnto-2-gem))

Answer (score 1):

Set your file as a partial and append preprend or do what you wana do with it.

For a partial file named _index.js.erb located in the same folder of where the file with this code is called will be prepend in the DOMID exemple.

```
jQuery('#exemple').prepend("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'index')) %>");
```

Maybe you can do a html file with it...

```
<% javascript_tag do %>

<%= render :partial => 'index' %>
```

or direct code

```
<% end %>
```