# RAILS_ROOT not longer valid when loading images with the prawnto_2 gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, prawn, prawnto

I'm in the process of upgrading my app from Rails 3.0 to Rails 3.1.

I've binned my old plugins in favour of gems where possible and that includes replacing the old prawnto plugin with this nice shiny new [prawnto_2](https://github.com/forrest/prawnto) gem.

Most things seem fine, but I can't get images to load as before. The code in my PDF view is

```
pdf.image open("#{RAILS_ROOT}/public/images/logo.png")
```

but I get the following error

```
uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::RAILS_ROOT
```

I realise that the location of the image file will change as I'm using assets and the image is no longer stored in the public folder.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`RAILS_ROOT` is in the global namespace, so you have to use

```
::RAILS_ROOT
```

However this is deprecated, so better use

```
::Rails.root
```

To append a path to this, you can use this, which also works on ...erm... *other operating systems*

```
::Rails.root.join('public','images','logo.png')
```